# Can benzene ring be the part of a acyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, phenols

Can *benzene* ring attached to *c=o i.e carbonyl group* be considered as a **acyl** group?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, acyl groups can be derived from all kinds of oxoacids.

According to the *[Glossary of class names of organic compounds and reactivity intermediates based on structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307),* acyl groups are defined as follows:

> Groups formed by removing one or more hydroxy groups from oxoacids that have the general structure $\ce{R_$k$E(=O)_l(OH)_m}\ (l\neq0)$, and replacement analogues of such acyl groups. (…) In organic chemistry an unspecified acyl group is commonly a carboxylic acyl group.

Especially concerning acyl groups derived from carboxylic acids in organic chemistry, the current version of [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013* (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001) defines:

> Carboacyl groups are $\ce{R-CO-{}}$, $\ce{-OC-R-CO-{}}$, or $\ce{-OC-R-[R'-CO-]_$x$-R''-CO-{}}$ groups and their functional replacement analogues, where $\ce{R}$, $\ce{R'}$, and $\ce{R''}$ are chains, rings, or ring systems, derived from carboxylic acids by the removal of the hydroxy group from each carboxylic acid group that is expressed by the suffix, and $x = 1 ,2,3$, etc.
>   (…)

In particular, benzoyl is explicitly mentioned as an example for an acyl group.